# PIL Internal Exception: {TypeError}getsize() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I get the exception referenced in the title using this code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
img = Image.open('test_fixtures/image00161.jpg')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.load_default().font
draw.multiline_text((20,20), 'some text', 'white', font)
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/davidparks21/opt/anaconda3/envs/xevo/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 329, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/home/davidparks21/ws/git/src/common/ml/scripts/FitnetsFAN/xf_plot_landmarks_test.py", line 18, in test_plt_landmarks_on_image
    self.ground_truth_landmarks, self.ground_truth_landmarks + 7)
  File "/home/davidparks21/ws/git/src/common/ml/scripts/FitnetsFAN/xf_plot_landmarks.py", line 63, in plt_landmarks_on_image
    draw.multiline_text((20,20), legends, 'white', font)
  File "/home/davidparks21/opt/anaconda3/envs/xevo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 234, in multiline_text
    line_spacing = self.textsize('A', font=font)[1] + spacing
  File "/home/davidparks21/opt/anaconda3/envs/xevo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 263, in textsize
    return font.getsize(text, direction, features)
TypeError: getsize() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

When I look at line 263 of `ImageDraw.py` the code is:

```
return font.getsize(text, direction, features)
```

This leads me to one of three possible conclusions:

- There's a version mismatch somewhere, but I can't see how
- There's a bug in PIL
- I'm using font wrong

Anyone want to venture a guess as to which it is? Or propose a new possibility?

FYI:

```
PIL.VERSION
'1.1.7'
PIL.PILLOW_VERSION
'5.0.0'
```

Comment: What's in `image`? If you give us a sample array, that will make this a perfect [mcve] that we can reproduce ourselves and see what might be happening differently on our systems.

Comment: A uint8 RGB image `[450, 450, 3]`, I added that code to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change below

```
font = ImageFont.load_default().font
```

to

```
font = ImageFont.load_default()
```

And it should work

Comment: Aha! Perfect, thanks! That did it. For some reason, it won't allow me to award the bounty for another 10 hours, so we wait...